# add event handlers every time a div changes

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

I am trying to add event handlers to a particular div that contains elements that change very often.
There are different tabs and each tab renders different data from an API when clicked on
The problem is that I need to add event handlers to some elements in each tab. When I add the event handler and the tab changes, the event handlers change also.

How do I:

- Set an event handler only after the page has loaded
- Every time the tab reloads

Answer (score 0):

You can check for element/elements update, and if they have changed, use `removeEventListener` on your target.

Another not so efficient, but still working option would be using `addEventListener` function's third argument for options. `{once: true}` will make your event listener happen only once, and then you check, if the element/elements have changed, than you attach another listener, or reuse the same. More on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I kept clearing the elements after I had selected them and then I was trying to update them even thought I had cleared them.

The solution is to to re-select them

for example:
when my program starts, I select the elements like this:

```
const ele = document.querySelector(".class")
```

and then some where in the code, I clear the parent element like this:

```
document.querySelector(".parentElementClass").innerHTML = "";
```

after clearing, I then try to use the cleared element like this:

```
ele.addEventListener...
```

which is wrong and that is where the error comes form.
What I have to do is to re-select the element again and then add the event listener like this:

```
const ele = document.querySelector(".class")
ele.addEventListener("...
```